# How i can make this shape in react native with text

Tags: react-native, button, radius, cornerradius

[Click on required image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btb3g.png)  I want to make a shape in react native but cannot find any solution over the net. If i make with customised top and bottom images explained in https://www.codedaily.io/tutorials/The-Shapes-of-React-Native. It will take extra height after writing any text that cause changing on corners height. Please help to complete this shape in react native

i have tried https://www.codedaily.io/tutorials/The-Shapes-of-React-Native. It will take extra height after writing any text that cause changing on corners height

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.